# How to have a custom URL structure for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls

Even though this question sounds like others here is my problem:

The site I am updating **had** a permalink structure of `/%postname%`, during this time I created a custom post type of "popups" (rewrite slug = 'popups') so the urls were:

```
/popups/the-post-name
```

**Now** the site has a blog, and the permalink structure has been changed to `/blog/%postname%`, this changed the custom post type url structure to:

```
/blog/popups/the-post-name
```

I want to keep the blog permalink structure as `/blog/%postname%` but I want to have a custom url structure for my custom post type that is not tied to the blog permalink. So instead of the urls for my custom post type of popups showing up as:

```
/blog/popups/the-post-name
```

I want it to show up as:

```
/popups/the-post-name
```

while retaining the blog permalink of `/blog/%postname%`

Comment: Did you move your WordPress installation to `blog` sub-directory?

Comment: /blog is not a sub-directory, its a prefix to the permalink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you registered the post type, one of the arguments was rewrite, which took an array.  make sure there's a `with_front` argument in the `rewrite` array, and set it to `false`.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    // other stuf...
    'rewrite' => array( 
         'slug' => 'popups',
         'with_front' => false
     ),
     // other stuf...
);

register_post_type( 'type', $args );
```

That should take care of it.

**Important:** Be sure to flush your rewrite rules after changing the code (go to settings > permalinks and hit save).

Comment: You don't have to hit save to flush your rewrite rules, just visiting the page will do it :)

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to attach /%year%/%month%/%postname%/ AFTER the slug? I'm in dire need of the code to attach that AFTER the slug, but BEFORE the postname. I would super-hugely-massively appreciate any help :)